# How to quickly code and run small C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing

There are times when I want to test new code from the forums or when I need to help my friends with specific C# problem. The problem is I don't want to create new "project" in Visual Studio each time just to code/run only this small code.

Java & Eclipse IDE comes up with "Scrapbook" feature which allows the execution of arbitrary Java expressions. What are the choices for C# programmers?

Comment: As with most old questions, the correct answer has changed in the meantime. If you have Visual Studio 2015 and don't want to spend money on LINQPad, definitely go with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38698819/237858

Answer (score 55, accepted):

<s>[Snippet Compiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/) is great for this.</s>

[LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is also good for testing out all sorts of C#, F# or VB code, not just LINQ queries.

---

**EDIT**

I suppose it's time that I mention that Snippet Compiler hasn't been updated in over five years, and is therefore no longer the best option.

However, I undersold LINQPad originally.  As Will Dean mentioned in the comments, LINQPad is excellent for all sorts of code, not just LINQ queries.  In fact, it has become an indispensable tool for me.  I use it daily, not only to quickly test out short snippets, but for relatively complex mini programs.  Its advanced output formatting makes it extremely easy to quickly examine intermediate and final results.

Comment: I find LINQPad is good for all C# stuff, not just LINQ.  I think it's misnamed

Comment: If you want to evaluate short expressions in LINQPad such as `1 + 2` or `"a,b".Split(',').Count()`, be sure to select "*C# Expression*" instead of the default "*C# Statement*" (which will execute but output nothing in this example, as would the same code in the expression window).

Comment: LINQPAD was a nice tool... but if you want CODECOMPLETION/INTELLISENSE you have to PAY...  so I turn to ROSLYNPAD a few years ago... and it is just EXCELLENT!!! also the excellent CSI.exe provided by VS2019 (c# interactive)... but if you want Intellisense you had to launch it from inside Visual Studio in "View->Other Windows->C# Interactive".

Answer (score 43):

A bit late to the party, but I came here while searching for this myself.

The best suitable solution for me was using the `C# Interactive`-window inside **Visual Studio** 2015 or later.
You can access it by opening it via `View` > `Other Windows` > `C# Interactive`, or by selecting some c# code and clicking on `Execute in Interactive` in the right-click context menu.

Here is a link on how to use it: http://dailydotnettips.com/2016/01/12/use-c-interactive-window-for-your-coding-experiment-in-visual-studio-2015/

I know it works in VS2015, I don't think it works in older versions.

Comment: Got here trying to to figure out the name and location in the application of the "C# Interactive" window. This definitely is the best answer now.

Comment: Thanks, this is the best answer to me. (+1)

Answer (score 20):

The website [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) seems like a nice option. It has code completion, code timing, and NuGet Package integration.

From their site:

> We are a group of .NET developers who are sick and tired of starting
>   Visual Studio, creating a new project and running it, just to test
>   simple code or try out samples from other developers.
>
> This tool was inspired by http://jsfiddle.net, which is just awesome.

In particular, I recommend trying out their MVC mode. On the left side of the screen choose `Project Type: MVC`.

Answer (score 18):

Here's what I do:

- Go to Tools->Options->ProjectsAndSolutions, and disable "Save new projects when created".
- Fire up a new VS, Ctrl-Shift-N to create a project, and use that.
- Use C# Express to have something that launches more quickly and has less clutter, but still enough power to do most things.

Answer (score 7):

I usually use csc directly from the command line

> C:\Users\Greg>csc /o- /debug+
>   Test.cs

Answer (score 6):

You can run a lot of things in the Immediate window (Debug >> Windows >> Immediate)

For example, you can run the following:
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\blah.txt", "Hi there!");

Answer (score 3):

Check also [Snippy](http://csharpindepth.com/Downloads.aspx) and the [Snippy Addin for Reflector](http://jasonhaley.com/blog/archive/2008/11/23/142521.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

There's also the interactive C# shell, built on top of Mono:

http://mono-project.com/CsharpRepl

That's similar to what other languages have (for example, irb with Ruby)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Introducing the Microsoft “Roslyn” CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/10/19/introducing-the-microsoft-roslyn-ctp.aspx).

The "C# Interactive" window is perfect for this.

Answer (score 3):

Late in here, but if you also want to share the code with others, then [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) is the best I have tried so far. For offline solutions, LINQPad definitely would have my vote as well, and not just for LINQ queries.

Answer (score 2):

I just use the scratch console application project that I've defined for just this purpose.  I cut out whatever is in the main program and go to town.  If I decide that I need to keep whatever I've prototyped, I create a new project and copy to it.  Since I do this all the time, the project's always in my recent-projects list, too.

Answer (score 2):

I use a batch file (csc.bat):
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9

For vb.net I use this batch file(vbc.bat):
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\vbc %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 /r:system.windows.forms.dll /r:system.data.dll /r:system.dll

For example: C:>csc testit.cs

Each will create a .net .exe file.
This solution is not so good for Windows Forms applications, however.

Answer (score 2):

**RoslynPad** - nice lightweight open-source alternative to LINQPad.

RoslynPad, https://roslynpad.net/

GitHub: https://github.com/aelij/RoslynPad

Answer (score 1):

This is something I've never liked about visual studio. One thing (and probally the only thing) I miss from VB6 was the ability to create a project, and run it without saving it or anything. Was great for just what you said.

I typically have at least one or two scrap projects of each type, (Console, Winforms, and Web), that I just rotate and use. This way I'm not always creating new projects.

Comment: This is a feature that you can disable / enable, at will, in Visual Studio. 
                                                                                                                     Go to : Tools-> Options-> Projects and Solutions. then uncheck  "Save new projects when created"

Answer (score 1):

you could have a look into C# Scripting.

[C# scripting](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cs-script_for_cp.aspx)

this is ment to allow you to build fast scripts without the use of the IDE.

HTH

bones

Comment: ok now i have seen the snipppy IDE, that looks like a better option :D

Answer (score 1):

I always keep a copy of Express Edition running; this can execute and debug projects without needing a proper file location (as long as you don't hit save). Does the job for me...

Answer (score 1):

Try SharpDevelop. It doesn't contain everything, but is good for quick examples. You can open a solution and easily swap out the code to test something else. In the project properties you can change a solution from console to window app via a combobox selection. You can easily translate your code from C# to Boo, Python, Ruby or VB, or from any of these languages to another, starting with whatever your source is. Therefore, if you go looking for a problem solution on the web and can't find one in VB - but do find one in C#, you may be able to convert it.

Answer (score 1):

There is an online web C# compiler and executor: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_csharp_online.php

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [ScriptCS](http://scriptcs.net/). It uses the Roslyn compiler to create a scripting language using C#.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio should be a better choice, but it is too heavy. Some simple tests, I often try here.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/learn/modules/csharp-write-first/2-exercise-hello-world

or use linqpad and vscode

> https://www.linqpad.net/
> https://code.visualstudio.com/