# Weird extension method overload resolution

Tags: c#, extension-methods, overload-resolution

I'm having trouble getting the compiler to resolve the correct overload for an extension method.  The best way for me to explain is with a little code.  Here's a [LINQPad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/384747/36388) script that demonstrates the problem.  This won't compile because of the problem I'm having:

```
void Main(){
    new Container<A>().Foo(a=>false);
}

interface IMarker{}
class A : IMarker{
    public int AProp{get;set;}
}
class B : IMarker{
    public int BProp{get;set;}
}
class Container<T>{}

static class Extensions{
    public static void Foo<T>(this T t, Func<T, bool> func)
        where T : IMarker{
        string.Format("Foo({0}:IMarker)", typeof(T).Name).Dump();
    }
    public static void Foo<T>(this Container<T> t, Func<T, bool> func){
        string.Format("Foo(Container<{0}>)", typeof(T).Name).Dump();
    }
}
```

There error I get is:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: '`Extensions.Foo<Container<A>>(Container<A>, System.Func<Container<A>,bool>)`' and '`Extensions.Foo<A>(Container<A>, System.Func<A,bool>)`'

It seems to me that it's not ambiguous at all.  The first method won't accept a `Container<T>`, only an `IMarker`.  It seems like the generic constraints aren't assisting in overload resolution, but in this version of the code, they do seem to be:

```
void Main(){
    new A().Bar();
    new A().Foo(a=>a.AProp == 0);
    new A().Foo(a=>false); // even this works
    new A().Foo(a=>{
        var x = a.AProp + 1;
        return false;
    });

    new Container<A>().Bar();
    new Container<A>().Foo(a=>a.AProp == 0);
    new Container<A>().Foo(a=>{
        var x = a.AProp + 1;
        return false;
    });
}

interface IMarker{}
class A : IMarker{
    public int AProp{get;set;}
}
class B : IMarker{
    public int BProp{get;set;}
}
class Container<T>{}

static class Extensions{
    public static void Foo<T>(this T t, Func<T, bool> func)
        where T : IMarker{
        string.Format("Foo({0}:IMarker)", typeof(T).Name).Dump();
    }
    public static void Foo<T>(this Container<T> t, Func<T, bool> func){
        string.Format("Foo(Container<{0}>)", typeof(T).Name).Dump();
    }

    public static void Bar<T>(this T t) where T : IMarker{
        string.Format("Bar({0}:IMarker)", typeof(T).Name).Dump();
    }
    public static void Bar<T>(this Container<T> t){
        string.Format("Bar(Container<{0}>)", typeof(T).Name).Dump();
    }
}
```

This compiles and produces the expected results:

> Bar(A:IMarker)
>   Foo(A:IMarker)
>   Foo(A:IMarker)
>   Foo(A:IMarker)
>   Bar(Container<A>)
>   Foo(Container<A>)
>   Foo(Container<A>)

It seems to only have a problem when I don't reference the lambda parameter in the lambda expression, and then only with the `Container<T>` class.  When calling `Bar`, there is no lambda, and it works fine.  When calling `Foo` with the return value based on the lambda parameter, it works fine.  Even if the lambda's return value is the same as the one in the example that doesn't compile, but the lambda parameter is referenced by a dummy assignment, it works.

Why does it work in these cases but not in the first?  Am I doing something wrong, or have I found a compiler bug?  I've confirmed the behavior in both C# 4 and C# 6.

Comment: @ManoDestra:  Edits because you don't like where I place my curly braces are not welcome.

Comment: This is C#. Hence the edit.

Comment: I fail to see your point.

Comment: [C# coding conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx)

Comment: For one, that document doesn't define brace placement.  For two, that is a set of guidelines, not strict rules.  For three, you are not the style police.  For four, please go troll someone else and stop trying to force my code to suit your personal taste.

Comment: It is not a matter of taste. Code on SO is edited in accordance with the coding standards for the language in question. It makes it far easier for everyone involved to adhere to the accepted coding standards. The code here is for everyone's benefit who use SO, not just the person asking the question. Hence why coding standards are employed. Not trolling in any sense, simply being helpful to others by editing according to standards same as every other editor on SO.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118440/discussion-between-p-daddy-and-manodestra).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, I got it after re-reading my own answer! Nice question =)
The overload does not work because it does not take constraint `where T:IMaker` into account while resolving overload (constraint is not a part of method signature). When you reference a parameter in lambda you (can) add a hint to the compiler:

1. This works:

   ```
   new Container<A>().Foo(a => a.AProp == 0);
   ```

   because here we do hint that a:A;
2. This does not work even with a reference to parameter:

   ```
   new Container<A>().Foo(a => a != null);
   ```

   because there is still not enough information to infer the type.

As far as I understand the specification, in "Foo scenario" the inference can fail on the second (Func) argument thus making the call ambiguous.

Here's what spec (25.6.4) says:

> Type inference occurs as part of the compile-time processing of a method invocation (§14.5.5.1) and takes place before the overload resolution step of the invocation. When a particular method group is specified in a method invocation, and no type arguments are specified as part of the method invocation, type inference is applied to each generic method in the method group. If type inference succeeds, then the inferred type arguments are used to determine the types of arguments for subsequent overload resolution.
>
> If overload resolution chooses a generic method as the one to invoke, then the inferred type arguments are used as the runtime type arguments for the invocation. If type inference for a particular method fails, that method does not participate in overload resolution. The failure of type inference, in and of itself, does not cause a compile-time error. However, it often leads to a compile-time error when overload resolution then fails to find any applicable methods.

Now lets get to pretty straightforward "Bar scenario". After type inference we will get **only one** method, because only one is applicable:

1. `Bar(Container<A>)` for `new Container<A>()` (does not implement IMaker)
2. `Bar(A)` for `new A()`(is not a Container)

And here's the [ECMA-334 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf), just in case.
P.s. I'm not 100% sure that I got it right, but I prefer to think that I grasped the essential part.

Comment: Okay, I'm with you so far with the constraints not being part of the method signature (which is also why you can't overload a method by constraint alone), and that the lambda parameter usage gives the compiler a hint to unambiguously choose an overload.  I suspected this.  But what I still don't get is why the calls to `Bar` work in my second snippet.  They completely lack the lambda.

Comment: I guess our answer is somewhere in 25.6.4 and 14.4.2 of language specification. But it's 7am for me so I won't be able to come up with any ideas until tomorrow.

Comment: Would you care to expand on that a little more in your answer, perhaps with some quotes from the spec?

Comment: I've added some information to my answer and polished it. Sorry, was thinking while writing so lots of edits)

Comment: I think you got it.  It's the type inference step that gets confused, and that's what I wasn't really thinking about.

Answer (score 1):

[Sergey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38579207/36388) figured out why what I was trying to do doesn't work, I think.  This is what I've decided to do instead:

```
void Main(){
    new A().Bar();
    new A().Foo(a=>a.AProp == 0);
    new A().Foo(a=>false);

    new Container<A>().Bar();
    new Container<A>().Foo(a=>a.AProp == 0);
    new Container<A>().Foo(a=>false); // yay, works now!
}

interface IMarker<T>{
    T Source{get;}
}

class A : IMarker<A>{
    public int AProp {get;set;}
    public A   Source{get{return this;}}
}
class B : IMarker<B>{
    public int BProp {get;set;}
    public B   Source{get{return this;}}
}

class Container<T> : IMarker<T>{
    public T Source{get;set;}
}

static class Extensions{
    public static void Foo<T>(this IMarker<T> t, Func<T, bool> func){}
    public static void Bar<T>(this IMarker<T> t){}
}
```

Unfortunately for me, this is a big change for my application.  But at least the extensions layer will be simpler, and in the end it will be less ambiguous for both the compiler and humans, and that's a good thing.

Comment: If Container is really a meaningful IMaker, then it looks like a nice refactoring decision.